# ckeditor_rails precompile config.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ckeditor

I have a rails 4.2 application using ckeditor_rails gem, version 4.5.3.

I've added a custom config file in /app/assets/ckeditor/config.js, as mentioned in the documentation at https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails. This gets precompiled correctly in application.js on production environment.

The problem is that after rake assets:precompile, a sample config file is created in /public/assets/ckeditor/config.js, most probably from the gem. And my configuration doesn't work (only after deleting this file in production).

Is there a way to except this file from being created? Or to be precompiled with the content of the file at /app/assets/ckeditor/config.js?

Answer (score 0):

This file is the precompiled configuration that you should set up in `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js`

Maybe you have an error in this file that stops the initialisation of ckeditor.

Check the console output of your web browser for errors.

If you don't need any configuration of ckeditor, set `app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js` to an empty file.

Comment: My file is very simple (just one config line) and it is precompiled properly in application.js. The problem is that the sample config file is also generated, and this is loaded after application.js is loaded, thus overwritting my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We've successfully deployed CKEditor into production:

[image]

[image]

It was a struggle to get all CKEditor's assets to precompile, but from what I can remember, you just have to make sure you're precompiling for the `production` environment:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

[image]

I don't remember any other options.

I'm available if you want to put up a repo and we can check to see if we can get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your offer. I did precompile for the production environment. That file is still generated, and I can't figure it out why. Maybe it's a bug in the gem.